# Combine Javascript accordion menu effects w/ jQuery filterable photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, combinations

I've created a ui concept for a website that requires the combination of two different code sources, but I don't really know how to bring them together properly as I am not that fluent in javascript.

I want to combine [this Javascript accordion menu](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-accordion/index.html) with [this filtered photo gallery plugin](http://mazeofminds.com/demo/filterable-portfolio/). Here's where it gets complicated.

I have beverage flavors to display as an online catalogue. I want to be able to filter these by division (i.e. Coffee, Food, Sugar, Tea), so I'm using the gallery plugin for the filter. On the gallery's demo page, instead of supermodels in the photos, just imagine title images for each section of products.

What happens right now when you click on an image is what I want to change. Instead of clicking on an image to see a larger lightbox version (using PrettyPhoto), I want to eliminate PrettyPhoto altogether and use the javascript menu to drop down underneath the photo to display a plain text list of flavors. If the user clicks the image again, the menu will swing back up into the photo and disappear.

Is there a way to hide my accordion menus within each image element and still be able to filter the results with all the animations and no glitches? And on-image-click the menu will display flavors over top of the surrounding images? (I don't want everything to be relatively positioned because the dropdown menu will knock everything around, unless I keep the results vertical and not in grid layout.)

Thanks for all your help in advance.  This one is really stumping me because I have no tutorials or support to go on.

Comment: You mean like this? http://i.imgur.com/UxZxO.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I haven't used the quicksand plugin, but the drop down accordion effect you want should be independent of the gallery's filter functionality. (again, not having used it, I can't say say for sure)

First I would drop the code base for the accordion menu and create your own drop down functionality. After inspecting the dom for the gallery page, what I would do is create a div element as the next sibling after the anchor tag on the image, setting it's display to none.  Add a jquery toggle event to the anchor element and then add the slideDown/slideUp functionality to the toggle event. (or a slideToggle method to a click event, less code, does the same thing). If you don't want more than one slide down menu to be open at once, then use a click event to hide all dropdowns, then show current dropdown.

Each li element would have to have a position relative (which is fine without any top, left, bottom, right properties), and each div element would have position absolute.  Think of it like a drop down navigation menu.

If the addition of the hidden div to the li element messes with the filter functionality, you could try creating a json object for each image with it's corresponding slidedown data and using a function to inject the data in a dynamically created div element.

*EDIT:  I must have missed it the first time I read, but what do you mean: *"And on-image-click the menu will display flavors over top of the surrounding images?"*

I thought you wanted the list of flavors to appear underneath the image in a drop down menu.  Are you saying you want the flavors to appear in drop down underneath and at the same time, cover the other images on the page?

*Edit 2: To answer your question..

```
$('a.somelink').toggle(function() {
    $(this).next().slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    $(this).next().slideUp(200);
});
```

Or

```
$('a.somelink').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    return false;
});
```

These two are fine if you don't mind having more than one drop down open at a time, but if you need only one open at a time then try this:

```
$('a.somelink').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == true ) {
        $(this).next().slideUp(200);
        $('a').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('a.somelink').removeClass('active');
        $('.sub_div').slideUp(200);
        $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(200);
    }
    return false;
});
```

*new Edit: your li elements should look like this:

```
<li class="item">
   <a href="#"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
   <div class="drop_down_content">Content in Drop down</div>
</li>
```

This layout should not change even after clicking the filter button

Comment: You are pretty spot on with everything. Here is an image to visualize what I'm imagining. [link](http://i.imgur.com/UxZxO.png)

Comment: How do you add a jquery toggle event to the anchor element?

Comment: Okay so I'm trying to implement your javascript but I'm seeing an issue with the way PrettyPhoto was integrated with the thumbnails. The link is actually just an image. It looks like this:

`<li class="item" data-id="id-1" data-type="hannah">
<a href="images/hannah_yg.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[portfolio]">
<img src="images/hannah_yg_thumb.jpg" width="210" height="130" alt="Yulia Gorbachenko, Hannah 1" /></a></li>`

So what do I put in place of `a.somelink`? Do I eliminate the PrettyPhoto portion altogether and wrap a link around the thumbnail photo, and then use that path?

Comment: Btw that's the first <li> element in the top left of the grid of thumbnails fyi.

Comment: In place of $('a.somelink'), you could put $('li.item a'). Sorry I should have made my example reflect your markup.  And yes, I thought that was what you wanted was to remove all trace of the PrettyPhoto plugin?  You still have to add the <div> containing your drop down content to the markup, as a direct sibling of the anchor tag that's wrapping your image thumbnail.

Comment: Okay everything is ALMOST exactly how I need it, save one bug.  When you're viewing "all", the dropdown works perfectly because in "all", each thumbnail is wrapped with <a>. Once you filter the gallery, however, the dropdown doesn't function anymore because each thumbnail is simply <li> at this point and the <a> class isn't targeted. So is there a way to target both the `<li>` and `('li.item a')` within the same call?

Comment: When I inspect the code before and after clicking the filter button, the contents of each <li class="item> element doesn't change. There is still only one child element, the <a> tag. And within that <a> element, only one child, the actual thumbnail image.  After clicking the filter button, the <a> element still exists. Not sure what you mean by: "each thumbnail is simply <li> at the point"..

Comment: I noticed in the plugin clones the entire gallery before starting the filter animations, this MIGHT have something to do with what you are talking about, however, it should be cloning all the markup you have created.

Comment: Well when I was inspecting the code in dreamweaver, before filtering anything I clicked on the thumbnail to reveal the drop down no problem. When you click on something in dreamweaver, in split view, with live view turned on, on the very bottom left underneath the source code it displays the chain of tags you're clicking within. So, when I click that thumbnail, it shows something like <html><body><ul><li><a>, showing that the <a> is being clicked and toggling the dropdown.

Comment: however, AFTER I filter the gallery, specifically to the section that my first thumbnail happens to end up in, I click on the thumbnail to find that the chain of tags now ends with <li> and not <li><a>. So this leads to believe this is why it's malfunctioning. I'm not sure why the <a> wouldn't remain, because that doesn't seem possible

Comment: that is correct, the <a> should be toggling the drop down.  The <a> never leaves, you are always clicking the <a> element, even after you click the filter button.  The order of elements should be: <div class="item"><a><img src="thubmnail.jpg" /></a><div class="drop_down_content">Content</div></div>

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you are talking about, when I ran a browser level test of the <a> element I was clicking on on the Gallery site, it wasn't registering as an <a> either....I will look into the clone() method, I think you need to set a flag to clone all data and event handlers. You might have to edit the plugin code

Comment: I've been looking into this further and can't figure it out. Have you had a chance to figure out anything?

Comment: Check my answer below, I didn't know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

First, here's how every `<li>` looks within the portfolio.

```
    <li class="item" data-id="id-1" data-type="hannah">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/hannah_yg_thumb.jpg" width="210" height="130" alt="Yulia Gorbachenko, Hannah 1" /></a>
        <div class="drop">International<br />Regional<br />International<br />
        </div>
    </li>
```

Then here's the .js that came with the gallery plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Blur images on mouse over
    $(".portfolio a").hover( function(){ 
        $(this).children("img").animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, "fast"); 
    }, function(){ 
        $(this).children("img").animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, "slow"); 
    }); 


    // Clone portfolio items to get a second collection for Quicksand plugin
    var $portfolioClone = $(".portfolio").clone();

    // Attempt to call Quicksand on every click event handler
    $(".filter a").click(function(e){

        $(".filter li").removeClass("current"); 

        // Get the class attribute value of the clicked link
        var $filterClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");

        if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {
            var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");
        } else {
            var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
        }

        // Call quicksand
        $(".portfolio").quicksand( $filteredPortfolio, { 
            duration: 800, 
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad' 
        }, function(){

            // Blur newly cloned portfolio items on mouse over and apply prettyPhoto
            $(".portfolio a").hover( function(){ 
                $(this).children("img").animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, "fast"); 
            }, function(){ 
                $(this).children("img").animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, "slow"); 
            }); 

            $(".portfolio a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                theme:'light_square', 
                autoplay_slideshow: false, 
                overlay_gallery: false, 
                show_title: false
            });
        });


        $(this).parent().addClass("current");

        // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

(Sorry for answering in an "answer" but I couldn't format the code otherwise..)

Comment: You haven't removed the calls to prettyPhoto yet...Also, I was thinking if it's possible, could email me your code? I mean the code you actually have been working on.